# OPUS source client for Icecast

Tags: audio-streaming, icecast, internet-radio

I am looking for the source client that would let me stream the OPUS audio through the Icecast2 streaming server.

The problem currently is that I am trying to establish an "internet-radio" for streaming the audio with very low bitrates. OPUS codec is very good for that purpose, but I cannot find a source client for Icecast2 which would allow encoding with the OPUS codec.

Comment: How low of a bitrate do you need?  AAC is pretty solid down to 48kbit, and you will have much better client support.

Comment: First of all, I should have mentioned that I use open formats only. Currently I run a streaming server with 32kbps Ogg Vorbis format which performs pretty well. However, I also need as low bitrates as 8kbps now, so OPUS support would be great for that.

Answer (score 1):

Next version of Darkice (verison 1.2) will have Opus support. http://darkice.googlecode.com

Right now I'm streaming Opus 32kbit/s using darkice svn revision 540 to an icecast 2.4 beta3 and receiving with VLC.

Comment: Does DarkIce support streaming from a list of files on HDD, and not from the soundcard?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simple utility for feeding the Ogg streams to IceCast server. It is called [oggfwd](http://v2v.cc/~j/oggfwd/). It supports both audio and video files and the OPUS-encoded files as well.

Answer (score 1):

Gstreamer has shout2send plugin which can send opus encoded ogg stream to icecast server.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=yourfile.flac ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw, rate=48000, channels=2, format=S16LE ! opusenc bitrate=128000 frame-size=40 ! oggmux ! shout2send mount=/stream.ogg port=8000 description="putsongnameherer" genre=JAZZ username=source password=yourpass ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but it looks like there is a fork of BUTT that has suppot for Opus.

https://github.com/krad-radio/butt-krad-opus

Comment: As I was struggling to compile on Windows, I tweeted the developer and he linked me to a binary: http://dev.kradradio.com/~oneman/opus-transmitter.zip

Answer (score 0):

Give LunarCaster DJ a try. http://lunarcaster.com

It's free and works with a number of different encoders including OPUS, OGG, AAC+, MP3 and WMA.

Comment: Can you please describe it more?

Comment: There is plenty of information on the website. Check out the screenshots page http://www.lunarcaster.com/index.php/screenshots . It's a windows application. Requires no database (uses xml as a database of sorts). Is there anything particular you would like to know?